# The IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding asynchronous method of this class

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asyncsocket

I have recently coded a Csharp server and client program where they can send messages to each other. I have started of basic and I ave run into a problem, when I connect the first client everything is fine, the messages send and receive fine from booth partys. When I add a second client I receive a Argument exception, shown in the image below.

Accept method:

```
public void NewConnection_Incoming(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket incomingMessageSocket = _incomingSocket.EndAccept(AR);
    string IP = incomingMessageSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
    byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "] New connection received on incoming socket.");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

    this._incomingSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(NewConnection_Incoming), _incomingSocket);

    incomingMessageSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length,
        SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceiveMessage), incomingMessageSocket);    
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: where is _incominSocket declared? is it a class level variable?

Comment: Yes, it is the server socket.

Comment: are you using the same socket instance for each request from different clients?

Comment: I have 2 different sockets, _incomingSocket, and _outgoingSocket

Comment: But each client that connects, the client connects to booth _incoming and _outgoing

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: can you try creating a socket for each connection on the server side?

Comment: I can try, I will reply with the result.

Comment: There must be another call to BeginAccept in your app.  Can you post that code?  The error indicates that when NewConnection_Incoming() was called, the AR parameter does not match a call to BeginAccept(_incomingSocket).  So it looks like a "double subscribe" kind of error, where the callback is registered to two different sockets, or there are two different BeginAccept calls going on with the same callback.

Comment: Use synchronous accept and use tasks for the other socket IO. APM is obsolete and by removing it the bug will go away, too.